# Using \cref and custom labels for inference rule names

Tags: labels, arrays, cleveref

I have an array environment that is used to present inference rules (via a custom command). Now, these inference rules have names and i would like to refer to them using \label and \cref commands.
I am guessing this is possible though the details elude me.

As a small example, this is the command:

```
\newcommand{\typerule}[3]{\ensuremath{\begin{array}{c}\textit{\scriptsize ({#1})} \\#2 \\\hline{\ensuremath{#3}}\end{array}}}
```

It produces an inference rule with hypotheses (#2), a line, a conclusion (#3), all topped by a name for the rule (#1).

My idea would be to add another parameter and something \label-style related to it, so that in the text later on i can use cleveref's \cref{} and then the name saved in the environment (and the related category name) pop up.

So i would write

```
\typerule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{labelidentifier}
```

and somewhere else

```
The \cref{labelidentifier} does ...
```

and the produced output should be something like

```
The rule name does
```

where *rule* is generated by cleveref and *name* is the one i specified previously.

Comment: Since you need to pick up a string of characters, not a counter, may be Heiko Overdiek’s `zref-titleref`, `\gettitlestring `and `nameref` have more to offer.

Comment: Well, @Sveinung, these are names i have not heard of before, i'll investigate, thanks! (working answers using them are still welcome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trick `cleveref` into thinking that “name” is the number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,cleveref}

\newcounter{typerule}
%%% standard format
%\crefname{typerule}{rule}{rules}
%%% more complex form
\crefformat{typerule}{#2rule~\textit{#1}#3}
\Crefformat{typerule}{#2Rule~\textit{#1}#3}

\newcommand{\typerule}[4]{%
  \def\thetyperule{#1}%
  \refstepcounter{typerule}%
  \label{#4}%
  \begin{tabular}{c}
  \scriptsize (\textit{#1}) \\
  $#2$ \\
  \midrule
  $#3$
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\typerule{modus ponens}{A\to B\quad A}{B}{MP}

\bigskip

The \cref{MP} does something.

\end{document}
```

I've also changed somewhat your command, in order to remove the acrobatic parts with `\ensuremath` and adding a better spacing with `\cmidrule`.

[image]

Comment: Woah, that works (almost) perfectly! I still had to fix some of my math stuff that I sent as arguments. But many many thanks!!

Just a clarification: the new counter is needed because it's a new "type" of reference, right? While the \def tells what to use as a name? the \def is the most obscure part.

Also, what code is using the "booktabs" package?

Comment: The label-ref mechanism, which is enhanced by `cleveref`, uses the counter's representation stored in `\the<counter>`, in this case `\thetyperule`. A `\refstepcounter` is needed in order to start the business and make `\label` do its work of writing the desired annotations in the `.aux` file; this will use whatever the current counter's representation is.

Comment: The impossibel is solved in an hour, the miracles take a little longer ... =:-)